# Adding to a custom list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to add a booking to a custom booking list.

This is the Booking class

```
public class Booking {
    String forename = null;
    String surname = null;
    int numberOfSeats = 0;

    public Booking() {
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
    }
```

In the other class, I have a list declared, have a method to add a booking to this list:

```
public class TheatreShow {
List<Booking> booking = new ArrayList<Booking>();

    public void addBooking(String forename, String surname, int numberOfSeats) {
    booking.add(numberOfSeats, surname, numberOfSeats);
}
```

The error I'm getting is that it's not applicable for the arguments.

```
The method add(int, Booking) in the type List<Booking> is not applicable for the arguments (int, String, int)
```

Comment: In the `addBooking` method you pass a `Booking` type parameter, or, you construct the object with your parameters and THEN you add it to the list.

Comment: So something like Booking booking1 = new Booking(forename, surname, numseats). Then I'll be adding a booking object to the list?

Comment: Yes, because the List's add method requires one reference type to be passed. You can read more on objects creation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create all args constructor:

```java
public class Booking {
    String forename = null;
    String surname = null;
    int numberOfSeats = 0;

    public Booking(String forename, String surname, int numberOfSeats) {
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
    }
}
```

Then you have to create new instance of the Booking and add it to the list:

```java
 public class TheatreShow {
     List<Booking> booking = new ArrayList<>();

     public void addBooking(String forename, String surname, int numberOfSeats){
        booking.add(new Booking(forename, surname, numberOfSeats));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
booking.add(numberOfSeats, surname, numberOfSeats);
```

To

```
booking.add(new Booking(forename, surname, numberOfSeats));
```

Your list is a list of `Bookings`, so it only stores items of type `Booking`. You need to create a new `Boooking` with the `forename`, `surname` and `numberOfSeats` you got by parameter before adding to the list.

Comment: Thank you, that's well explained